# WaitForSingleObject p/invoke on 64-bit

Tags: c#, winapi

In my application, I use p/invoke and call WaitForSingleObject:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern UInt32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr hHandle, UInt32 dwMilliseconds);
```

Then event is registered and

```
uint res = WaitForSingleObject(eventHandle, 0xFFFFFFFF);
if (res == 0x00000000)
{...}
```

The application runs ok in Windows XP 32-bit but it fails to return a value on systems such as Windows 7 64-bit. Does anyone have any idea why this happens on 64-bit systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your p/invoke is correct. The only plausible explanation for the call to WaitForSingleObject never returning is that the event never becomes signaled.

As an aside, it would seem to me to be simpler to use EventWaitHandle instead of p/invoke.